# MongoDB aggregation pipeline project several values from the same id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am struggling with mongoDB pipelines. I am working on a MERN stack that processes data.

We ask people questions with a form, a form is described as a session, e.g. one session per people. Each session is recorded in a table like that :

```
{ _id: 1, created_at:"01/01/2021"}
{ _id: 2, created_at:"02/01/2021"}
{ _id: 3, created_at:"03/01/2021"}
```

All of their answers are stored in a table like that the foreign key being sessionId:

```
{ _id: 1, value:"Name1", sessionId : 1, typeofField :"name"}
{ _id: 2, value:"Firstname1", sessionId : 1, typeofField :"firstname"}
{ _id: 3, value:"Date of birth1", sessionId : 1, typeofField :"birthdate"}
{ _id: 4, value:"Name2", sessionId : 2, typeofField :"name"}
{ _id: 5, value:"Firstname2", sessionId : 2, typeofField :"firstname"}
{ _id: 6, value:"Date of birth2", sessionId : 2, typeofField :"birthdate"}
```

How can I project this data to have every informations of a session in order like this :

```
{id :1, created_at:"01/01/2021", name : "Name1", firstname: "Firstname1", birthdate : "Date of Birth1"}
{id :2, created_at:"02/01/2021", name : "Name2", firstname: "Firstname2", birthdate : "Date of Birth2"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?   Stackoverflow protocol is to post your initial attempts or thought process.

Comment: As always, *strongly* recommend you use real datetimes in MongoDB, not "MM/DD/YYYY" strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution, going in the other direction (from answers to session):

```
c = db.answers.aggregate([
    // Bring all answers together as a k-v array:                                                                     
    {$group: {_id: "$sessionId", flds: {$push: {k: "$typeofField", v: "$value"}}}}

    // Do a 1:1 lookup:                                                                                               
    ,{$lookup: {from: "session", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "Z"}}

    // We now have flds as a k-v array.  We know that Z[0] cotains both                                               
    // created_at and _id.  We seek to create a full k-v array that we can                                            
    // turn into the target object, so working the expression below "backwards"                                       
    // 1. Pull element 0 from the Z array                                                                             
    // 2. Turn that into a k-v array, e.g. [{k:_id,v:1},{k:created_at,v:02/01/2021}]                                  
    //    with $objectToArray.  Important: we pick up _id here.                                                       
    // 3. Concat the flds k-v array with the Xsession lookup k-v array                                                
    // 4. We now have a complete k-v representation of our data.  Use $arrayToObject                                  
    //    to turn (e.g.) {k:created_at,v:02/01/2021} into created_at:02/01/2021                                       
    // 5. Don't assign the object to a fld (like X).  Instead make that object the                                    
    //    new root.  newRoot is the only arg to $replaceRoot:                                                         
    ,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot:
        {$arrayToObject:
           {$concatArrays: [ "$flds", {$objectToArray: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Z",0]}} ] }}}}

]);
```

Or if you want more control over the fields instead of picking up everything in the `sesssion` doc:

```
c = db.answers.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$sessionId", flds: {$push: {k: "$typeofField", v: "$value"}}}}
    ,{$lookup: {from: "session", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "Z"}}

    // Don't want all the fields from the lookup?  No problem: wrap the                                               
    // $objectToArray with a filter and only let k = [_id,created_at,foo]                                             
    // or whatever else you want.  Make sure to always include _id.                                                   
    // Of course, if you want to exclude fields and keep the rest, just use                                           
    // the $not operator.  Be sure not to exclude _id; see commented cond below:                                      
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: {$concatArrays: [ "$flds",
                     {$filter: {input: {$objectToArray: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Z",0]}},
                                   as: "z",
                                cond: {$in: ["$$z.k", ["_id","created_at","foo"]]}
                                //cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$z.k", ["foo"]]}}                                             
                               }}
                                                               ]
                                               }}
                    }}
]);
```

Depending on the amount of material looked up in `session`, you may want to use the fancier version of `$lookup` to filter the fields there:

```
c = db.answers.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$sessionId", flds: {$push: {k: "$typeofField", v: "$value"}}}}
    ,{$lookup: {from: "session",
                let: { sid: "$_id" },
                pipeline: [
                    {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$sid" ]} }},
                    {$project: {"_id":true, "created_at":true,"foo":true}}
                ],
                as: "Z"
               }}
    ,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot:
        {$arrayToObject:
           {$concatArrays: [ "$flds", {$objectToArray: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Z",0]}} ] }}}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for it:

1. Find all answers for a session with `$lookup` stage
2. Convert all the answers to an object like: `{ [typeofField]: value }`
3. Merge all the answers to a single object
4. Finally merge the newly converted `answers` object with the root document (`$$ROOT` the document of sessions collection)

In case you don't understand the pipeline, I've created a mongodb playground ([Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DxyoxwhVTo-)) so go and try executing one stage at a time.

Kindly refer to the docs for **stages** and **operators** used in this pipeline yourself. [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup), [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields), [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject), [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects), [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot), [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/).

**Note:** Make sure that the value used for the `as` field in the `$lookup` stage doesn't appear in *answers* collection for `typeofField`, otherwise it will get erased for the `$unset` stage. So for the pipeline below the *answers* collection should not contain `{ ... typeofField: "allAnswers" ... }`.

#### Pipeline

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "answers",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "sessionId",
      pipeline: [
        { $addFields: { keyValue: [["$typeofField", "$value"]] } },
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$keyValue" } } },
      ],
      as: "allAnswers",
    },
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [{ $mergeObjects: "$allAnswers" }, "$$ROOT"] },
    },
  },
  { $unset: "allAnswers" },
]
```

For pre-5.0 users, use this lookup:

```
    $lookup: {                                                                                                        
      from: "answers",                                                                                               
        let: { sid: "$_id" },                                                                                         
        pipeline: [                                                                                                   
            { $match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$sessionId", "$$sid"]}} },                                                      
            { $addFields: { keyValue: [["$typeofField", "$value"]] } }                                                
            ,{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$keyValue" } } },                                          
        ],                                                                                                            
        as: "allAnswers",                                                                                             
    },
```

Comment: Note:   Only starting in MongoDB 5.0 can `localField` and `foreignField` be used with `pipeline`.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti  I already knew that from the docs but I assumed that user is running the latest version. Thanks for the edit <3.